# Query a Custom collection of collections in LINQ

Tags: linq, collections

I have custom type name **Netsgroup** which is a collection of  **Net** class.

**Net** class , contsains:  *Netname* and list of string *Parts*.

```
class Netsgroup:  CollectionBase
{
 // a collection of nets
    public Net[] nets
    {
        get { return (Net[]) this.InnerList.ToArray(typeof(Net)); }
    }
}

public class Net
{

    string netname;
    public string Netname
    {
        get { return netname; }
        set { netname = value; }
    }


   List<string> parts= new List<string>();
    public  List<string> Parts
    {
        get { return parts; } 
    }
}
```

An example of Netsgroup is:

> Net1   u1, u2, u3
>
> Net2   u4,u5,u3
>
> Net3   u4,u6, u7

Each line is with Netname and Parts.

I want to find the duplicates in the Netsgroup  collection.

Like:

> net1, net2  has u3
>
> net2, net3 has u4

How can I intersect the Parts from all Nets to find duplicates?

Thanks, Avi.

Comment: Your `nets` getter is weird. You return mutable collection, but mutating it doesn't do anything to the internal collection. I think you should either return `IEnumeable<Net>` or a read-only `IList<T>`. Also, you might want to look into auto-implemented properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think doing this would be easiest using LINQ:

```
var duplicates =
    from net in netsgroup.nets
    from part in net.Parts
    group net by part into g
    where g.Count() >= 2
    select g;
```

If you want to write the results in the format you specified into console, you can use something like:

```
foreach (var dup in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0} has {1}", string.Join(", ", dup.Select(n => n.Netname)), dup.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> parts1 = netGroup1.nets.SelectMany(n => n.Parts);
IEnumerable<string> parts2 = netGroup2.nets.SelectMany(n => n.Parts);

IEnumerable<string> intersectedNets = Enumerable.Intersect(parts1, parts2);
```

Comment: But there aren't just the two sets, there are many of them. And doing `Intersect()` for each pair of them is ineffective.

Comment: @svick,   Oh.  I thought he wanted to compare two Netgroups.  It is only one Netgroup?  Just the duplicates inside one Netgroup?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I understood it.

Comment: Ok my answer probably doesn't solve the problem.  But I will leave it up because it might be useful incase he wants to do something similar to this.